# android - dagger classess not found in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm learning dagger , I've some problems with it . android studio doesn't recognize dagger classess , for example it doesn't find @Component , @Inject and others.

this is my gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
        implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.24'
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.24"
```

If I write @dagger.Component , it finds it but it doesn't have others like Inject

what is wrong with it ?

Comment: try with clean and rebuild project again